# Accessing Results View from variable in code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq

[image]

As shown in the above image, when I press on the ResultsView, it opens a new list which contains `[0]` and `[1]`. However, in my code, when I write `sessionQueryable[0]` it says syntax error.
How can I access what's in the ResultsView?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The debugger is showing you the *internal* structure behind the `IQueryable` interface, but you should not program against that, though, since there is no guarantee that you'll get the same structure each time.

`IQueryable` lists cannot be accessed by index using `[]`.  You'd need to turn it into an `IList` to access it by index:

```
var list = user.Sessions.ToList();
```

Or query the sessions by some other method using the `IQueryable` interface, for example `Skip()` and `Take()`:

```
var first  = sessionsQueryable.Take(1);         // First item
var second = sessionsQueryable.Skip(1).Take(1); // Second item
```